# clearInterval of another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some integrations between games and Philips Hue API to have my light syncing with games.

I have a function `bombPlanted()` that triggers a bunch of things, including another function called `blinkLight()` which is in charge of switching on/off the light every second.

I use an interval to change the state every second. However, I'm not able to stop this interval outside of the `blinkLight()` function. Here is my current code:

```js
let isBlinking = false;
let isBombPlanted = false;
let isBombExploded = false;
let userTeam = '';

async function getLightData(light) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${hueAPI}/lights/${light}`);
        const body = await response.json();
        const state = body.state;
        return state;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

function updateLightData(light, body){
    const request = fetch(`${hueAPI}/lights/${light}/state`, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })

    request.then(async response => {
        try{
            const request = await response.json()
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    })

}

function blinkLight(light, interval){
    return setInterval(async () => {
        const state = await getLightData(light);
        if(state.on === true){
            updateLightData(42, { on : false });
        }else{
            updateLightData(42, { on : true });
        }
    }, interval);
}

function bombPlanted(){
    let bombCountdown = 40;
    updateLightData(42, colors.bomb);
    return blinkLight(42, 1000);
}

/* TESTS */

bombPlanted();
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(bombPlanted()) }, 3000)
```

I'm returning `setInterval` from `blinkLight` and returning `blinkLight` from `bombPlanted` to get sure I can use the interval ID outside of `bombPlanted`, however what I try at the end seems not stopping the interval.

Comment: you... call clearInterval with the id that setInterval created. that's the only way you can clear an interval, so you must make the id available where you need it.

Comment: Following up on Kevin's point: If you use a `let` instead of a `const` and declare it in the shared parent scope you'll be able to access it in `bombPlanted`; but be careful once you have two functions sharing the same variable.

Comment: Ok, while you were answering I just tried something else. Instead of returning the setInterval with the `blinkLight()` function, I just created a `blinkInterval` variable, which I pass the setInterval when I'm doing blinkLight, and then I'm able to cancel it outside. It seems to be following what you say.

So there's no other way when I trigger an interval in a function, to stop it outside of it, without passing it to a variable that is globally available?

Comment: @Floran: It doesn't have to be *globally* available, no.  For example, the function which creates the interval can return the identifier for that interval (which your function does), and consuming code can use that identifier (which your code does not).  However you track the identifier for the interval, that's the value you need to clear it.

Comment: What I don't show in my code is the example I made to try to stop the blinkLight().

What I tried to do is to trigger bombPlanted(), then using a setTimeout to stop the setInterval started through blinkLight(). But it was not working :

`
bombPlanted();
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 5000)
`

Comment: You don't need blinkLight to be async. Just have it return the integer from setInterval and capture it in an assignment `const handleToClear = blinkLight(...);`

Comment: @Floran: If you have some other code which isn't included in the question and you're actually trying to ask about that code, please update the question to include the code you're actually trying to ask about as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith: unfortunately, I'm waiting for an API response to continue, so I need to be async right?

Comment: @David: I just updated the example code so you have more context. So let's say here I return the `setInterval` from`blinkLight()`. But from this point, I'm confused.

Comment: @Floran: It's not clear what you're confused about.  The value returned from `setInterval` is the value you'd use in `clearInterval`.  The code shown never calls `clearInterval`, nor ever does anything with the value returned from `setInterval` (other than return it from a function, but nothing uses it after that).  Note also [as previously mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483825/clearinterval-of-another-function#comment136600235_77483825) that `blinkLight` *itself* doesn't need to be `async`.  If you do keep it `async` then the returned value is a `Promise` to be resolved.

Comment: @David: I'm not clear on how to write it. And I tried many attempts that were unsuccessful so I preferred to let it blank for the example. `blinkLight` is triggered through `bombPlanted`, so I guess I also have to return `blinkLight` from `bombPlanted`. Then I should call `bombPlanted` and stop the blinking effect with `clearInterval(bombPlanted())` ? This seems not working. Also, I changed `blinkLight` to not be async

Comment: @Floran: `setInterval` returns a value. `blinkLight` returns that value, wrapped in a `Promise`. You can store that value in a variable. For example: `blinkLight().then(x => someExistingVariable = x)` Then, wherever you plan to call `clearInterval`, you would use the value that's in `someExistingVariable` (which needs to be in scope for both of these operations, of course). Any way you organize it, the value returned by `setInterval` is the value you'd provide to `clearInterval`. It sounds like you're very much over-thinking this.

Comment: @David : Sorry I don't understand, and as a tech newbie stackoverflow layout is not really helping me, your message is so small, so tight, without space.
Let me recap : now `blinkLight` is not async anymore, so it returns the `Timeout` object, which is what I need to use in `clearInterval` if I understand correctly. But `blinkLight` is always called through my function `bombPlanted`. So if I want to be able to use the `Timeout` object in the environment where I trigger `bombPlanted`, I need to do `return BlinkLight()` on `BombPlanted`. Am I right? I don't see otherway to reuse interval

Comment: @Floran: Correct, if you want to return a value from `BombPlanted` then you would use the `return` keyword, exactly like you do in `blinkLight` already.  Consuming code can then use that value however you like.  You are very much encouraged to make an attempt.  If that attempt does not work as expected in some specific way, you can update the question to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example.

Comment: @David: I did the change. You can now see that `blinkLight` returns the `setInterval`, and `bombPlanted` returns `blinkLight` so I can use it in my parent context.

Comment: So does it mean it is mandatory first to store the first call in another variable, and then use this variable to stop the interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is starting 2 interval timers:

```
bombPlanted();
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(bombPlanted()) }, 3000)
```

You start one interval immediately with the top-level `bombPlanted()` call. Then in 3 seconds you start a second one and clear it immediately. So the first timer keeps going.

You should assign the result of `bombPlanted()` to a variable, then clear that in 3 seconds:

```
let bombTimer = bombPlanted();
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(bombTimer), 3000);
```